# How to get the difference of current month for the current year data and previous year same month in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

[New Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsvMw.png)

How to get the difference of current year current month total and previous year same month data in ssrs report while using mdx query..
I want to display the result in new column.

check this image :

[image]

Comment: If your MDX script is returning data from both years you can use a matrix component, check [this](http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com.co/2012/10/lesson-15-ssrs-matrix-reports.html).

Comment: Hi Zuleta, yeah it is returning both years data, but i don't know how to subtract both years data.. I am already using matrix only, i didn't use MDX script i am directly fetching data from cube..

Comment: please see the above image, in that i want the data for 2016 august sales order minus 2015 august sales order total..

Comment: It can be done but you have to provide more details about your matrix. Maybe a screenshot of the matrix in the design window.

Comment: Already i added the screen short(Check this image)..

Comment: what this expression ll gives the result..Sum(Fields!Products.Value) - Previous(Sum(Fields!Products.Value))

Comment: Can any one help on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataset returns data only from 2015 and 2016 years:

```
=SUM(
    IIF(
      MAX(Fields!Year.Value)=Fields!Year.Value,
      Fields!Products.Value,
      0
    )
 )
 -
 SUM(
    IIF(
      MIN(Fields!Year.Value)=Fields!Year.Value,
      Fields!Products.Value,
      0
    )
 )
```

If your dataset returns data from multiple more than two years you have to explicitely use the years you want to compare.

```
=SUM(
    IIF(
      LCase(Fields!Month_Year.Value)=MonthName(Today.Month) & "-2016",
      Fields!Sales_Order.Value,
      0
    )
 )
 -
 SUM(
    IIF(
      LCase(Fields!Month_Year.Value)=MonthName(Today.Month) & "-2015",
      Fields!Sales_Order.Value,
      0
    )
 )
```

**UPDATE:** Expression include `Month` validation to determine if the row corresponds to the current month, I assume your month field returns the month name i.e "August".

With the description you provided in your question and comments this could help you as start point. Good luck

Comment: It gives difference of current year current month and previous year same month.. Ex: total of 2016 August - total of 2015 August

Comment: @chakri, How is the structure of your dataset? Without more details it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Your second script may be useful, In that i want to include current month for this year and for previous year also.. How to add Month in your script...

Comment: @Zuleta, I added new image, if you see that image you come to know clear structure

Comment: @chakri, I've updated the second expression to check the current month. Include the new image in your question.

Comment: @chakri, try to analyze that expression to figure out how to adjust it to your dataset. Without see your dataset there is no much I can do. Is `Month_Year` a text field that contains `August-2016`.

Comment: @Zuleta, I removed Lcase its working fine.. Thank you very much for spending time on this issue...

Comment: @chakri, great! if my answer solved your issue you can select it as the correct answer. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)